# Delphi components install utility console application

Tags: delphi, registry, components, installation, delphi-7

Well I'm stumped.
I'm writing an installation support add-on for Smart Install Maker that will install some components for me- AlphaControls :)

And the add-on is a console application. But for some reason [down in the code] for adding packages to the "Known Packages" registry location, it wants to add an additional registry entry, even though the array size is only setup for 3. It's trying to add a .DPK file, even though the array is setup for .BPL. Soo... what the hell????
It works and all, except for that last nagging bit it tries to add.
Compile size is about 97/98k, after optimizing and compressing shrinks down to about 48k

So I guess my question is, can anyone spot the error I seem to be overlooking?
YES I KNOW- INNO SETUP, but... I've already spent the money on Smart Install Maker so I gotta use it.
No compile errors, justs adds an extra non .bpl file to registry

Code is as follows...

```
{Smart Install Maker installation support for components}
{for Delphi 7.0 environment only}
program pakghlp;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  Registry;

var  SPath,
   BPLPath,
   IDERoot,
   DPKName: string;

const
 BaseName = 'AlphaControls';

 PackageRoot = 'AlphaControls\';

 DPKFiles: array[1..5]
  of string = ('acntD7_R.dpk',
               'acntD7.dpk',
               'aceD7_R.dpk',
               'aceD7.dpk',
               'AlphaDB7.dpk');

 DPKArraySize = 5;

 BPLFiles: array[1..3]
 of string = ('aceD7.bpl',
              'acntD7.bpl',
              'AlphaDB7.bpl');

 BPLDetails: array[1..3]
 of string = ('AlphaControls extra',
              'AlphaControls',
              'AlphaControls DB-aware pack');

 BPLFileQty = 3;

  LookFor: array[1..2] of string = ('*.dcp','*.bpl');
  LookForQty = 2;

  RegPath = ';$(DELPHI)\Components\AlphaControls';

procedure InitVariables;
var
    RegKey: TRegistry;
 TargetKey: string;
   LibPath: string;
begin
 RegKey:= TRegistry.Create;
   try
     RegKey.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
     TargetKey:= 'Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0';
     if RegKey.OpenKeyReadOnly(TargetKey) then
       begin
        IDERoot:= RegKey.ReadString('RootDir');
        RegKey.CloseKey;

        TargetKey:= 'Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Library';
        RegKey.OpenKeyReadOnly(TargetKey);
        SPath:= RegKey.ReadString('Search Path');
        LibPath:= RegKey.ReadString('Package DPL Output');
        RegKey.CloseKey;

        LibPath:= StringReplace(LibPath,'$(DELPHI)','',[rfIgnoreCase]);
        BPLPath:= IDERoot + LibPath + '\';
       end;
    finally
     RegKey.Free;
    end;
end;

procedure GetListing(const SearchFor: String; ImportList:TStringList);
var SrchResult : TSearchRec;
begin
if FindFirst(SearchFor, faAnyFile, SrchResult) = 0 then
  begin
    repeat
     ImportList.Add(SrchResult.name);
    until FindNext(SrchResult) <> 0;
    FindClose(SrchResult);
  end;
end;

procedure GetBaseNames(Listing: TStringList);
var TempList: TStringList;
           i: integer;
    BaseName: string;
begin
  TempList:= TStringList.Create;
  TempList.Delimiter:= ';';
  TempList.DelimitedText:= SPath;
  Listing.Clear;
  for i:= 0 to TempList.Count - 1 do
    begin
    BaseName:= TempList[i];
    StringReplace(BaseName,'$(DELPHI)','X:\Dummy\Folder',[rfIgnoreCase]);
    Listing.Add(ExtractFileName(BaseName));
    end;
  TempList.Free;
end;

function AlreadyExists: boolean;
var CheckList: TStringList;
            i: integer;
    Installed: boolean;
begin
  CheckList:= TStringList.Create;
  GetBaseNames(CheckList);

  for i:= 0 to CheckList.Count -1 do
   begin
     if CheckList[i] = BaseName
      then Installed:= true;
       if Installed = true then break;
     Installed:= false;
   end;
CheckList.Free;
Result:= Installed;
end;

procedure ProcessIDE(InstallType: integer);
var RegKey: TRegistry;
  TempList: TStringList;
       i,j: integer;
  NewSPath,
  RegName,
  RegValue,
  DelEntry: string;
begin
RegKey:= TRegistry.Create;
  case InstallType of

    0:  begin {-uninstall}
         TempList:= TStringList.Create;
         TempList.Delimiter:= ';';
         TempList.DelimitedText:= SPath;
         DelEntry:= copy(RegPath,2,Length(RegPath));
         for i:= 0 to TempList.Count - 1 do
          begin
            if TempList[i] = DelEntry
            then
             begin
              Templist.BeginUpdate;
              Templist.Delete(i);
              TempList.EndUpdate;
             end;
          end;
          NewSPath:= TempList.DelimitedText;
          try
            RegKey.RootKey:= HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
            RegKey.OpenKey('Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Library',false);
            RegKey.WriteString('Search Path',NewSPath);
            RegKey.CloseKey;

            RegKey.OpenKey('Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Known Packages',false);
            for i:= 0 to BPLFileQty do
              begin
                RegName:= BPLPath + BPLFiles[i];
                RegKey.DeleteValue(RegName);
              end;
          finally
            RegKey.CloseKey;
          end;
         TempList.Free;
        end;

    1:  begin {-install}
          SPath:= SPath + RegPath;
          try
            RegKey.RootKey:= HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
            RegKey.OpenKey('Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Library',false);
            RegKey.WriteString('Search Path',SPath);
            RegKey.CloseKey;

            RegKey.OpenKey('Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Known Packages',false);
            for j:= 0 to BPLFileQty do
              begin
                RegName:= BPLPath + BPLFiles[j];
                RegValue:= BPLDetails[j];
                RegKey.WriteString(RegName,RegValue);
              end;
          finally
          RegKey.CloseKey;
          end;
        end;
  end;
RegKey.Free;
end;

procedure CompilePackage(PackageName: String; Wait: Boolean);
var
  StartInfo : TStartupInfo;
  ProcInfo : TProcessInformation;
  CreateOK : Boolean;
begin
  FillChar(StartInfo,SizeOf(TStartupInfo),#0);
  FillChar(ProcInfo,SizeOf(TProcessInformation),#0);
  StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  CreateOK := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(PackageName), nil, nil,False,
              CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP+NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
              nil, nil, StartInfo, ProcInfo);
  if CreateOK then
    begin
      if Wait then
        WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    end
  else
    begin
      WriteLN('Unable to compile: ' + DPKName);
     end;
  CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
end;

procedure ProcessPackages;
var Package: string;
          i: integer;
const DCC32 = 'DCC32 ';
begin
  for i:= 1 to DPKArraySize do
  begin
    DPKName:= ExpandFileName(GetCurrentDir + '\..')
            + '\' + PackageRoot + DPKFiles[i];
    Package:= DCC32 + '"' + DPKName + '"';
    CompilePackage(Package,true);
    Sleep(500);
  end;
end;

procedure ProcessFiles(InstallType: integer);
var TempList: TStringList;
    MoveList: TextFile;
         i,j: integer;
    FileFrom,
      FileTo,
   ParentDir,
  SearchType: string;
begin
  case InstallType of

    0:  begin {-uninstall}
          AssignFile(MoveList,'pakghlp.dat');
          Reset(MoveList);
            while not eof(MoveList) do
              begin
                readLn(MoveList,FileFrom);
                if FileExists(FileFrom)
                then DeleteFile(PChar(FileFrom));
              end;
          CloseFile(MoveList);
          DeleteFile(PChar('pakghlp.dat'));
        end;

    1:  begin {-install}
        ProcessPackages;
          if FileExists('pakghlp.dat') then DeleteFile(PChar('pakghlp.dat'));
           AssignFile(MoveList,'pakghlp.dat');
           Rewrite(MoveList);
           ParentDir:= ExpandFileName(GetCurrentDir + '\..') + '\';
           TempList:= TStringList.Create;
          for i:= 1 to LookForQty do // file extension types
            begin
              SearchType:= ParentDir + PackageRoot + LookFor[i];
              GetListing(SearchType,TempList);
              for j:= 0 to Templist.Count - 1 do
                begin
                  FileFrom:= ParentDir + PackageRoot + TempList[j];
                  FileTo:= BPLPath + TempList[j];
                  CopyFile(PChar(FileFrom),PChar(FileTo),False);
                  DeleteFile(PChar(FileFrom));
                  WriteLn(MoveList,FileTo);
                end;
            end;
          CloseFile(MoveList);
        end;
  end;
TempList.Free;
end;

procedure InstallComponents;
begin
  InitVariables;
  if AlreadyExists then ProcessFiles(1) // refresh corrupt .dcu's.
  else
    begin // didn't previously exist
      ProcessFiles(1);
      ProcessIDE(1);
    end;
end;

procedure RemoveComponents;
begin
  InitVariables;
  ProcessFiles(0);
  ProcessIDE(0);
end;

{ ----- Console Application Begins Here ------- }
begin
  if ParamCount =  0 then exit;

  if ParamStr(1) = '-install'
    then InstallComponents;

  if ParamStr(1) = '-uninstall'
    then RemoveComponents

  else exit; // garbage trap
end.
```

Comment: You've succumbed to the "sunk cost" fallacy. You've spent money on something, and you think that obliges you to use it, but that money is gone whether you use it or not! You can get a better tool without spending any additional money, so who cares how much you spend on the inferior product? Pretend you spent it on the free product instead, if that makes you feel better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You issue it seems related to the index used to iterate over the BPLFiles array. which is 1 index based and you are using a 0 index based.

```
const
     BPLFiles: array[1..3]
     of string = ('aceD7.bpl',
                  'acntD7.bpl',
                  'AlphaDB7.bpl');
```

Chage this code

```
for i:= 0 to BPLFileQty do
    begin
      RegName:= BPLPath + BPLFiles[i];
      RegKey.DeleteValue(RegName);
    end;
```

To

```
for i:= 1 to BPLFileQty do
    begin
      RegName:= BPLPath + BPLFiles[i];
      RegKey.DeleteValue(RegName);
    end;
```

And this code

```
        for j:= 0 to BPLFileQty do
          begin
            RegName:= BPLPath + BPLFiles[j];
            RegValue:= BPLDetails[j];
            RegKey.WriteString(RegName,RegValue);
          end;
```

To

```
        for j:= 1 to BPLFileQty do
          begin
            RegName:= BPLPath + BPLFiles[j];
            RegValue:= BPLDetails[j];
            RegKey.WriteString(RegName,RegValue);
          end;
```

Comment: well all be damned. I must of looked over that section at LEAST a dozen times and it was staring right at me. LOL. I changed it and it works perfectly now. A few other things [not shown above] was fixed also. As for the fallacy, yeah I guess your right. But since its working beautifully now thanks to your help, i'm keeping it.